# Importance of Needham–Schroeder Protocol

Tags: model-checking, security, research, protocols

I'm working on a paper about model checking on cryptographic protocols and many of the papers I have read, base their approaches in the Needham-Schroeder protocol. I undestand this was one of the earliest security protocols for authentication and that Lowe's findings makes it an interesting protocol to talk about, I get that it is also one of the easiest protocols to explain and that's why it is used on textbooks, I have also read about how it led to the creation of some modern protocols like SSL. However it felts somewhat strange for me that even modern research keeps on using it for their work instead of the fixed version or some other similar protocols.

Does this protocol has a set of features that makes it kinda "perfect" for research about verification or something like that, what am I missing?

Comment: It might be just a historical coincidence.

Comment: I guess it is a convenient example for textbooks. Since the protocol is very small, it it easy to introduce. Also, it seems correct, when actually there's a flaw. Hence it showcases the topic quite well.

Comment: I suspect you have already answered your own question.  You listed about 4 good reasons for using Needham-Schroeder as a test case for demonstrating new analysis methods.  That seems like a reasonable answer to your own question -- I'm not sure why you've rejected those reasons.